# How can I detect "collision" when my player is inside of another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The player jumps to let's say tile 2. Just like Mario. And then on it he presses j to load the other scene or whatever.

So I put an invisible object on top of the 2 tile, so if he is inside that invisible object, he can press j.

The problem is that, the j only works if I press j right when I collide. I need it to work when I'm inside.

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D colisor)
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("j") && (colide))

    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(Cena3);
        Debug.Log("he's in the last scene");
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D colisor)
{
    colide = true;
    Debug.Log("inside");
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D colisor)
{
    colide = false;
    Debug.Log("Outside");
}
```

Comment: Could you use `OnTriggerEnter2D` and `OnTriggerExit2D` to set/unset the flag and then move this logic to `Update` based on that flag...

Comment: What do you mean by flag ?

Comment: Just some boolean field nothing special, `bool IsInside` for example, then you can check that boolean field within the update method...

Comment: It doesn't detect when i'm inside the object. Just when i collide and out of it. Neither enter or exit helps...

Comment: Do you meant something like this ? I updated my code above.

Comment: Except to move the code from `OnTriggerStay2D` to `Update`

Comment: I don't know how to move that to update. Do i have to write something differently ?

Comment: Literally cut-paste. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html

Comment: Just the body of the method, you don't need `OnTriggerStay2D` anymore.

Comment: Got it. the (Collider2D colisor) was troubling me. So i just wrote without that. void  OnTriggerStay2D(). Im a really noob at this. Thanks man. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("j") && colide)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(Cena3);
        Debug.Log("he's in the last scene");
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D colisor)
{
    colide = true;
    Debug.Log("inside");
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D colisor)
{
    colide = false;
    Debug.Log("Outside");
}
```